# RiakCS Object Integrity?

Tags: riak, integrity, cloud-storage

I'm comparing different open source cloud storage technologies. I would like to know if Riak Cloud Storage (RiakCS) has any mechanism to preserve the integrity of the objects stored in it - like Openstack Swift's [Integrity Audit](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/overview_architecture.html#auditors), or Ceph's [scrub](http://wiki.ceph.com/03FAQs/02Operations_FAQ#How_Does_Ceph_Ensure_Data_Integrity_Across_Replicas.3F). I couldn't find that information in their documentation or via google. I would appreciate if someone could shed some light on this!

Comment: Ceph's _scrub_ is a joke: when data is corrupted Ceph clients receive invalid data silently (without any errors whatsoever); _scrub_ merely identifies inconsistencies between OSDs and manual(!) repair is necessary because Ceph does not know which replica is OK and which is corrupted. Bitrot and data corruption is inevitable on Ceph.
LizardFS and GfarmFS are way more reliable than Ceph in regards to data integrity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, yes. RiakCS sits on top of Riak and this is a snippet from the 1.3 release notes:

Introduced Active Anti-Entropy. Riak now has active anti-entropy. In distributed systems, inconsistencies can arise between replicas due to failure modes, concurrent updates, and physical data loss or corruption. Pre-1.3 Riak already had several features for repairing this “entropy”, but they all required some form of user intervention. Riak 1.3 introduces automatic, self-healing properties that repair entropy on an ongoing basis.

Best Regards,
Paul